# Deploying webapp generated using Jhipster in amazon web services (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster

I have used **Jhipster** to generate  a web app and i worked on top of it to redesign the web app as per my requirements.

Then i generated war using the command as below:

```
  mvnw package -Pprod -DskipTests
```

Now i want to deploy that web app to **Amazon Web Services**. I have tried all the ways jhipster suggested me to do.

**1. [Direct AWS](https://jhipster.github.io/aws/) 

2. [Boxfuse](https://jhipster.github.io/boxfuse/)**

I have tried uploading the generated war directly to **S3 bucket** also,  but uploading fails.

Using **boxfuse**, i have configured everything as per documentation and i tried uploading.

It gives me the following error in the cmd prompt while uploading war to the aws console.

```
 Push failed (Connection reset by peer: socket write error)
```

Please suggest me a way to upload the war generated to AWS and deploy in EBS there.

Comment: `Push failed (Connection reset by peer: socket write error)` sounds like a temporary network issue between your machine and S3 (where the Boxfuse Vault is hosted). Simply retry and it should work.

Comment: thanks mate...  but the  fact is we are trying this from two weeks before.....

Comment: As I said this is a direct link between your machine and S3. Retry and this should work. Cheers, Axel

Comment: I have tried Axel... I can push the war to the aws.. but there comes a new error saying Procfile or application.jar doesn't exist.... Even though I have procfile in the jhipster generated code......where I have to put this file in aws.. pleaSe suggest me

Comment: I am afraid there may be some confusion and things may have gotten mixed up here as Boxfuse doesn't use any procfile.

Comment: Error
A problem occurred while uploading to S3. This is what i am getting eventhough  my network has high speed and no issue with that. Pleas help me Axel

Comment: Please open a support request in the Boxfuse Console with the exact error message and debug logs and we'll be happy to look into it.