# Deploying a web app (java + angular) develops using jhipster in Amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, jhipster, cloudcaptain

I have developed a web app using jhipster ( java + angular)

Now I want that app to be deployed in AWS. I have tried using the sub generator provided in the jhipster website. But not able to deploy. Tried Boxfuse also. Not able to deploy as I get some error. Then tried uploading the war manually in Elastic Beanstalk. But not able to deploy successfully.

Finally I come with an idea of VM where I can start the application in Dev mode and forward the port for hitting from other machines..

Now my question.

I need to have 20+ such instances(sub domains).. Is that affordable cost wise?
Is there any other way to deploy easily.
Where can I find help for deploying an app in AWS (coz that cost me 20 days)?

Anyone has any documents or links which can be useful for me.

Even I am ready to pay who can really help me in sorting this out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As you did not give any details about your failures, I doubt someone can help you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239554/aws-deployment-failed-jhipster-app-ebs?noredirect=1#comment73549384_43239554

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43164737/deploying-webapp-generated-using-jhipster-in-amazon-web-services-aws?noredirect=1#comment73474305_43164737

Comment: Above two are my recent questions for the same.. pls anyone help me on this

Comment: I'p confused, you have accepted one anwser and got valuable hint on the other question. Try heroku sub generator if you can't debug the é thers.